# Function programming in Python

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

I'm trying to define a new function called `new_f`, just for practice:
The purpose of function is:

```
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
y = new_f(x)
print(y)
```

And that should give:

```
['4', '3', '2', '1']
```

So it's a reverse of x. 
 I tried something like this:

```
def new_f(x):
    y = len(x)
    for z in range(y-1,-1,-1):
        r = print([x[z]])
    return r
```

But that gives:

```
['4']
['3']
['2']
['1']
```

Ok, that's not what I want, so maybe:

```
---------
for z in range(y-1,-1,-1):
        r = [x[z]]
return r
```

And I get:

```
['1']
```

So he goes through all `z` and gives me the last one.
How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: list reverse is `list[::-1]`

Comment: What's the `for z in range(y-1,-1,-1)` loop iterating on?

Comment: `list[::-1]` means you've masked the built-in function `list()` with a reference to an object of type `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initial `r` as an empty list and append the elements to it and at last return the `r`

```
def new_f(x):
    y = len(x)
    r=[]
    for z in range(y-1,-1,-1):
        r.append(x[z])
    return r
```

But there are some elegant and more pythonic ways for reversing a list like reverse indexing :

```
the_list[::-1]
```

or built-in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) function :

```
reversed(the_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Kasra that's exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python's slicing operator to reverse a list.

```
def new_f(x):
        return x[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd find them useful:

```
def reverse_list(x):
    return x.reverse()

def reverse_list(x):
    return x[::-1]

def reverse_list(x):
    yield from reversed[x]
```

Comment: Hey, I think instead of `yield from reversed(x)` you can just do `return reversed(x)`. I mean it's the same exact thing, just shorter, and faster.

Comment: oh, yes. It's returns list_reverseiterator empty instance but yield returns a generator empty instance, that's the only difference :D